# Bring an AsyncImage to the top of the Screen SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I got the problem that whatever I tried didn't work to bring the informations on the bottom of the picture right under the pokemons picture. What can i do to fix this?

```
struct PokeDetailView: View {
 var pokemon: ViewModel.PokeMon
 var body: some View {
  VStack{
   AsyncImage(url: URL(string: "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/\(pokemon.id).png")) {
    image in image
     .image?.resizable()
     .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
     
   }
   
   
   VStack{
    Text("\(pokemon.name.english)")
    HStack{
     Text("Type: ")
     Text("\(pokemon.type[0])")
     Image("Pokemon_Type_Icon_\(String(pokemon.type[0]))")
      .resizable()
      .frame(width: 20,height: 20)
     
     if(pokemon.type.count > 1){
      Text("\(pokemon.type[1])")
      Image("Pokemon_Type_Icon_\(String(pokemon.type[1]))")
       .resizable()
       .frame(width: 20,height: 20)
      
     }
     
    }
    
   }
  }
 }
 
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3WxK.png

Comment: Get rid of `.frame(width: 300, height: 600, alignment: .top)` You will find that with SwiftUI the more you hard code values the more bugs you will encounter

Comment: okay i did that now